# Remove 'Wordpress' from tab title in error page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to remove 'Wordpress' title from the error page tab as shown in the screenshot,

[image: 1]

I tried the below code, it worked with all admin pages except the error pages

```
add_filter('admin_title', 'my_admin_title', 10, 2);
function my_admin_title($admin_title, $title)
{
   return get_bloginfo('name').' &bull; '.$title;
}
function custom_login_title( $login_title ) {
   return str_replace(array( ' &lsaquo;', ' &#8212; WordPress'), array( '
   &bull;', ' -New Name’),$login_title );
}
add_filter( 'login_title', 'custom_login_title' );
```

Comment: Do you have more information to provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's coming from wp-include/function.php, so you need to overwrite this at line number 3121 ()

Comment: <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change tagline change on wordpress admin panel?
Log in to the WordPress Admin Dashboard with the username and password you set for the new website.
In the left-hand menu, go to Settings -> General Settings.
In the dashboard area, Site Title and Tagline are the first sections you want to customize.

To see further please look:
https://colibriwp.com/blog/how-to-change-site-title-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

I was only capable of solving this issue for myself by overwriting the default wp_die_handler.
This creates a lot of redundant code if you only want to change the title but, on a broader scope, gives you the opportunity to redesign this whole error page.
If anyone finds a smoother way, hit me up.

1. Overwrite the callback

```
add_filter( 'wp_die_handler', 'custom_die_callback', 10 );
function custom_die_callback($callback){
 return "custom_die_handler";
}
```

2. Create the handler and enter your title.

```
if( ! function_exists('custom_die_handler') ){
    function custom_die_handler( $message, $title = '', $args = array() )
    list( $message, $title, $parsed_args ) = _wp_die_process_input( $message, $title, $args );

  $title = "CUSTOM_TITLE";

    if ( is_string( $message ) ) {
        if ( ! empty( $parsed_args['additional_errors'] ) ) {
            $message = array_merge(
                array( $message ),
                wp_list_pluck( $parsed_args['additional_errors'], 'message' )
            );
            $message = "<ul>\n\t\t<li>" . implode( "</li>\n\t\t<li>", $message ) . "</li>\n\t</ul>";
        }

        $message = sprintf(
            '<div class="wp-die-message">%s</div>',
            $message
        );
    }

    $have_gettext = function_exists( '__' );

    if ( ! empty( $parsed_args['link_url'] ) && ! empty( $parsed_args['link_text'] ) ) {
        $link_url = $parsed_args['link_url'];
        if ( function_exists( 'esc_url' ) ) {
            $link_url = esc_url( $link_url );
        }
        $link_text = $parsed_args['link_text'];
        $message  .= "\n<p><a href='{$link_url}'>{$link_text}</a></p>";
    }

    if ( isset( $parsed_args['back_link'] ) && $parsed_args['back_link'] ) {
        $back_text = $have_gettext ? __( '&laquo; Back' ) : '&laquo; Back';
        $message  .= "\n<p><a href='javascript:history.back()'>$back_text</a></p>";
    }

    if ( ! did_action( 'admin_head' ) ) :
        if ( ! headers_sent() ) {
            header( "Content-Type: text/html; charset={$parsed_args['charset']}" );
            status_header( $parsed_args['response'] );
            nocache_headers();
        }

        $text_direction = $parsed_args['text_direction'];
        $dir_attr       = "dir='$text_direction'";

        // If `text_direction` was not explicitly passed,
        // use get_language_attributes() if available.
        if ( empty( $args['text_direction'] )
            && function_exists( 'language_attributes' ) && function_exists( 'is_rtl' )
        ) {
            $dir_attr = get_language_attributes();
        }
        ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php echo $dir_attr; ?>>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?php echo $parsed_args['charset']; ?>" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <?php
        if ( function_exists( 'wp_robots' ) && function_exists( 'wp_robots_no_robots' ) && function_exists( 'add_filter' ) ) {
            add_filter( 'wp_robots', 'wp_robots_no_robots' );
            wp_robots();
        }
        ?>
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html {
            background: #f1f1f1;
        }
        body {
            background: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #ccd0d4;
            color: #444;
            font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
            margin: 2em auto;
            padding: 1em 2em;
            max-width: 700px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .04);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .04);
        }
        h1 {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;
            clear: both;
            color: #666;
            font-size: 24px;
            margin: 30px 0 0 0;
            padding: 0;
            padding-bottom: 7px;
        }
        #error-page {
            margin-top: 50px;
        }
        #error-page p,
        #error-page .wp-die-message {
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 1.5;
            margin: 25px 0 20px;
        }
        #error-page code {
            font-family: Consolas, Monaco, monospace;
        }
        ul li {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            font-size: 14px ;
        }
        a {
            color: #0073aa;
        }
        a:hover,
        a:active {
            color: #006799;
        }
        a:focus {
            color: #124964;
            -webkit-box-shadow:
                0 0 0 1px #5b9dd9,
                0 0 2px 1px rgba(30, 140, 190, 0.8);
            box-shadow:
                0 0 0 1px #5b9dd9,
                0 0 2px 1px rgba(30, 140, 190, 0.8);
            outline: none;
        }
        .button {
            background: #f3f5f6;
            border: 1px solid #016087;
            color: #016087;
            display: inline-block;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 13px;
            line-height: 2;
            height: 28px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0 10px 1px;
            cursor: pointer;
            -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            border-radius: 3px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
            box-sizing:         border-box;

            vertical-align: top;
        }

        .button.button-large {
            line-height: 2.30769231;
            min-height: 32px;
            padding: 0 12px;
        }

        .button:hover,
        .button:focus {
            background: #f1f1f1;
        }

        .button:focus {
            background: #f3f5f6;
            border-color: #007cba;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #007cba;
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #007cba;
            color: #016087;
            outline: 2px solid transparent;
            outline-offset: 0;
        }

        .button:active {
            background: #f3f5f6;
            border-color: #7e8993;
            -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
        }

        <?php
        if ( 'rtl' === $text_direction ) {
            echo 'body { font-family: Tahoma, Arial; }';
        }
        ?>
    </style>
</head>
<body id="error-page">
<?php endif; // ! did_action( 'admin_head' ) ?>
    <?php echo $message; ?>
</body>
</html>
    <?php
    if ( $parsed_args['exit'] ) {
        die();
    }
    {   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
add_filter('wp_title', 'remove_wordpress_from_title', 10, 3);
function remove_wordpress_from_title($title, $sep, $seplocation) {
    return str_replace('WordPress', '', $title);
}
```